# What does the social idiom "not received" mean in 19th century America?

Tags: british-english, idiom-meaning, southern-white-vernacular-english

I am struggling with a use of the word "received" that I have never seen before, in conjunction with a social status in 19th century America. Specifically, in Margaret Mitchell's *Gone With The Wind,* Chapter VI, Cathleen gossips to Scarlett that Rhett Butler is attending the barbecue because he is "Not received." I am writing a piece that spans this period and would like to know the scope and meaning of that cultural idiom.

### Scene summary

- Scarlett O'Hara has been playing the field of beaus at the party and spots Rhett who looks out of place. She's drawn to his "bad boy" vibe and seeks out gossip on him from Cathleen. Cathleen tells Scarlett that he is "not received," which excites Scarlett and she prompts Cathleen for an explanation.
- Cathleen explains Rhett's terrible reputation, that he took a girl out on a date, brought her home late with no chaperone, and the next day refused to marry her. The girl's brother called him out (for a shotgun wedding), Rhett claimed nothing happened but was challenged just the same. Rhett won the duel and killed the brother, and had to leave town "and now nobody receives him."
- The result was that the girl did not get pregnant but was "ruined just the same." I don't know if that ties in to the condition.

**I would like to know** what the idiom means, and if it would be understood to an 1860's British society as well because my story spans those two cultures. (If there was a different equivalent in England that would be helpful)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

He's not accepted in society.

In particular, if he tried to call on a lady, or a gentleman, he would be told the other person was "not at home," even if he had seen other visitors *received* just before, or just after, his attempt.  Calls being the basic unit of society in those days, dinners and balls being larger and more fancy, if you won't be received, you are not in society.

It was, in fact, [a practice to receive such visitors weekly, and a matter of great importance](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/35123/35123-h/35123-h.htm):

> If your circle of visiting acquaintance is very large, while at the same time your time is fully occupied, or your home duties make it inconvenient to dress every morning to receive visitors, it is a good plan to set aside one morning in the week for a reception day.. . . .

> Your friends will, unless there is some especial reason for a call in the interval, pay their visit upon the day named.
>
> Let nothing, but the most imperative duty, call you out upon your reception day. Your callers are, in a measure, invited guests, and it will be an insulting mark of rudeness to be out when they call. Neither can you be excused, except in case of sickness.
>
> Having appointed the day when you will be at home to see your friends, you must, for that day, prepare to give your time wholly to them. The usual hours for morning receptions are from twelve to three, and you should be dressed, and ready for callers, at least half an hour before that time.

<sub>*The Ladies' Book of Etiquette, and Manual of Politeness* by Florence Hartley, Boston 1860</sub>

Comment: I upvoted this answer because it is accurate and useful. To make it even better, you might include in the text of your answer the title and publication date of the book of etiquette that you link to and quote in the second part of your post; doing so is a simple and potentially valuable way to preserve the identity of the source in case something happens to the hyperlink to make it nonfunctional.

Comment: Florence Hartley seems to have been American, but I'm sure the practice, and probably the terminology, were similar in Britain.

Comment: Thank you, this and the referrence as a whole will prove very valuable! One thing about this particular scenario that confused me was the fact that Rhett had championed the challenge in a duel, which I had always assumed restored you honor. That was the purpose of a duel, I believed. Being called out, winning, and still lose your “society” seemed malapropos. Or are honor and society different?

Comment: @VogonPoet My sense is that dueling in the 19th century could have mixed implications for one's honor. You could be considered a coward for turning down a duel, but you could also be vilified and even charged with murder for killing someone in a duel. (See, for example, Aaron Burr, whose reputation suffered immensely after he killed Alexander Hamilton.) However, there seem to be a lot of subtleties, attitudes were different in different regions, and I'm no expert.

Comment: Prompted me to look up the Code Duello which covers Rhett’s scenario in Rule11: “ Offenses originating or accruing from the support of ladies' reputations, to be considered as less unjustifiable than any others of the same class, and as admitting of slighter apologies by the aggressor: this to be determined by the circumstances of the case, but always favorable to the lady.” So it was a lesser offense. Now, if Rhett refused, he would be “not received” as a coward. If he lost, his debt would be paid. But winning and losing your honor still? Charleston was a hard town if Mitchel is right.

Comment: Although…another commenter elsewhere showed that Scarlett was an unreliable narrator, so Mitchel may have wanted the reader to see this duplicity so we would question the narrative. IOW, her narrative may have intentionally deviated from the proper causes for being “not received.”

Comment: This is not really relevant to the question, but I can't help noticing that the author of the quoted text characterises the hours 'from twelve to three' (presumably noon to 3 PM, i.e. the early afternoon) as 'the usual hours for **morning** receptions' which seems to be at odds with the standard dictionary definitions of *morning*. It would be interesting to explore, in another question, if and when such use of *morning* was standard.

Comment: @VogonPoet a duel is not a trial. You demand a duel (roughly) when the other person's behavior is so odious that their continued existence is an insult to you. Often, the callout alone was enough to make both parties reach some accommodation, but it's a very strong "or else". That doesn't say anything about third parties though (note e.g. hw many duels Andrew Jackson fought about his wife). Perhaps no-one else felt that Rhett was odious enough *to their affairs*, but they likewise had no desire to allow him to be part of their affairs. So they screened his calls.

Comment: Duels are not legally binding.   You can not force people to receive you by fighting one.

Comment: You demand a duel when you have been dishonored, and you either win and your honor is restored with the offender's death (or whatever the exit condition for the duel was), or you lose and it is restored in your death (although that's not much comfort).  The duel has no impact on the offender's honor either way, unless they refuse it.  Even if your adversary wins it doesn't erase their gaucherie.  They still did whatever they did that made you call for the duel.  They just don't have cowardice added on top of their previous offense.

Comment: @jsw29 for preliminary research, you may find the history of matinee useful

Comment: Good answer, but it could be improved by explaining the apparent contradiction; if Rhett is not received, then how did he come to be at the party in the first place?  It seems unlikely that the party was open to the public, so in some sense Rhett had either been invited or his social status allowed him to attend the event, when he perhaps would not have been received at a social call.

Comment: This exchange is appropriate for questions of what the words mean,  the question of whether the passage is contradictory is better suited to Literature.   Such as, whether the woman was being hyperbolic

Answer (score 9):

An early meaning of "received" was "accepted or approved" (this still lives on in the phrase "received pronunciation", which refers to the high-class British accent). So when Rhett is described as "not received", it means that proper society didn't approve of him.

Answer (score 9):

I think it means he won't be asked over, and if he comes, the door won't be answered.

[Merriam-Webster *receive*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/receive)
verb
3a : to permit to enter : admit
b : welcome, greet

Comment: Typically the door _will_ be answered by a servant: "Her ladyship is not at home".